# getting random element from array within a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, random

I am trying to print to `console.log` the chosen weapon from an array I have inside of a function. I am learning javascript

I've tried `function(weapon) {` and I've also tried returning `randWeapon`, but not sure how to call the random element.

```
    function randomWeapon() {
      let weaponArray = ["rock", "stick", "bat", "shoe"];
      return (rand = weaponArray[Math.floor(math.random() * weaponArray.length)]);
    }
    console.log(randomWeapon());
```

I want to either pass the weapon to another function or display in `console.log(randWeapon)`

error `msg` is :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: math is not defined

Comment: `math` rewrite as `Math`? here -> `math.random()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo in your code, just replace **math** with **Math**

```
function randomWeapon() {
  let weaponArray = ["rock", "stick", "bat", "shoe"];
  return (rand = weaponArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * weaponArray.length)]);
}
console.log(randomWeapon());
```